How do I translate between different date formats?
In daily work I frequently toggle between excel style date and normal date.
For example, 42637 in Excel date format, is actually 2016 Sept 24th, Saturday in the "Long Date Format".
Is there a way to develop a vim function, such that when I trigger it via hotkeys (e.g. pressing 'g' then 'd'), it will read the current line of the cursor, get the number, translate it into Long Date Format, and show it, either as prompt tips or under the current line?
I'm more interested in the tech approach on how to implement such a feature. If some similar examples could be suggested it would be quite helpful. The transforming logic I can do it myself.

You can either fetch what's under the cursor with :expand('<cword>') or you can analyse the current line with getline('.') + matchstr()....
Then, handling dates is done with the wrappers around the usual POSIX functions: strftime() (to generate) and strptime() (to decode). However, the epoch handled is expressed in seconds since 1st jan 1970. You'll have a bit of conversion to apply between the excel epoch reference and the usual one.

:h strftime()
:h strptime()

Which could translate into
nnoremap <silent> µ <cmd>echo strftime('%Y %b %d, %a', (expand('<cword>') - 25567) * 24 * 3600 )<cr>


I have tried run :nnoremap gd <Cmd>echo strftime('%Y %b %d, %a', (expand('<cWORD>') - 25567) * 24 * 3600)<CR> but nothing happened when i press gd; running :nnoremap gd:<Cmd>echo strftime('%Y %b %d, %a', (expand('<cWORD>') - 25567) * 24 * 3600)<CR> also has no effect; adding one more space before semicolon, i.e. running :nnoremap gd :<Cmd>echo strftime('%Y %b %d, %a', (expand('<cWORD>') - 25567) * 24 * 3600)<CR> it would complain "E488: Trailing charracters"; putting such lines in ".vimrc" also has no effect. May I ask what is the right syntax to use?

I've just copy-pasted the previous line in my Vim 9.1.0442 and it works like a charm. May be, your version is older. In that case, you could replace <cmd> with :<c-u>.

BTW, of course it has no effect: it just displays the corresponding date (assuming I've correctly guessed the offset). To replace what's under the cursor, it would be something like :nnoremap <silent> µ ciw<c-r>=strftime('%Y %b %d, %a', (@" - 25567) * 24 * 3600 )<cr>

I notice you use µ in the line. Can  i use gd> as I mean to type g then t as the hotkey.

Yes my Vim is 8.2.12. When i in command line type nnoremap gd <c-u>echo strftime('%Y %b %d, %a', (expand('<cWORD>') - 25567) * 24 * 3600)<CR>, then in any line with number 41272 type gd, weirdly on the first row of the file, it inserted  strftime('%Y %b %d, %a', (expand('<cWORD>') - 25567) * 24 * 3600)<CR> .... is there something wrong with my vim?

Yes, you can use gd or whatever you prefer. µ is my go-to key to draft and test mappings (as I have it on my keyboard, I take advantage of it). Also gd is much to precious as far as I'm concerned to override it -- I use and over-use Goto Definition feature.

Regarding <cmd> replacement. It's not supposed to be <c-u>, but :<c-u>.

thank you! nnoremap gd :<c-u>echo strftime('%Y %b %d, %a', (expand('<cWORD>') - 25567) * 24 * 3600)<cr> indeed works. my vim version is 8.2.12, <cmd> does not work.
